# dbx, solaris: selectively enable/disable shared libraries to instrument for memory access check?

Tags: dbx

```
(dbx) check -access
```

Turns on access checking an instruments at load time all shared libraries that the application uses.
Is there a way to selectively indicate which libraries should/not be instrumented?
I have a large application which uses a lot of shared libraries that take forever to instrument. Most of those shared libraries I'm not concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with rtc skippatch:

rtc skippatch lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4...